# How should I indicate the same comment to several answers?

Tags: discussion, comments

I think it's not really appropriate to paste the same comment in several answers, but occasionally I'll come across a question where multiple answers have taken the same approach, and that approach needs to be clarified or challenged in comments. If I just comment the top-most one, there's no great probability that the readers who would hopefully benefit from my comment will see it. What's the right approach here? Just hope enough people see it?

Comment: I’d comment to the question then, noting that all/most of the answers do something that isn’t the right approach.

Comment: If you're specifically addressing a problem in each answer then I see no problem with commenting on all the answers. There's no other way to ensure that each answerer will read it.

Comment: Also note that if you choose just one answer to make the comment on, and it's fixed, you should really delete your comment, and if the answerer decides to delete their answer because they can't fix the problem (a perfectly acceptable response) then your comment is now gone.  Making it on each problematic answer prevents these problems.